# Why /t/ after /k/ sometimes is pronounced like a mild aspirated T but sometimes is pronounced like unaspirated T?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

See this word:

**doctor** `/ˈdɑːktər/`, the `/t/` in this case seems to be like a mild aspirated T (that is there may have a bit air coming out of your mouth) [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/doctor_1?q=doctor).

But **expected** `/ɪkˈspektɪd/`, the `/t/` in this case seems to be like an unaspirated T (that is there is no air coming out of your mouth) [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/expect?q=expect)

& **attractive** `/əˈtræktɪv/`, the `/t/` in this case seems to be like an unaspirated T (that is there is no air coming out of your mouth) [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attractive?q=attractive)

**Is there any source that mentions about this issue?**

Updated:

I recorded my own voice of unaspirated T  & aspirated T in attractive, please check it

**unaspirated T**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLZjVzVG4taHBsUVk/view

**aspirated T**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLWnR5SGM1Tlh4NVk/view

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be imagining differences that don't exist in the minds of native speakers. The actual amount of air released there will vary with every utterance and occasion. No one hears these as one bit different from one another.

Or perhaps you have not heard enough examples.

If your first language considers the two sounds to be completely different phonemes instead of merely two allophones of the same phoneme, then you may be being overly sensitive to something you should not "notice", since native speakers do not do so.

Comment: I updated my question & I recorded my own voice of pronouncing unaspirated T & aspirated T of "**attractive**". I think they are very different. Nonnative sees things differently from native. I am sure they are very different.

Comment: We think that /l/ and /r/ are very different. Lots of people whose native language is Japanese can't tell them apart. For /kt/ before an unstressed syllable, we don't notice whether or not the /t/ is mildly aspirated.

Comment: @Tom Do you understand what allophones are? They’re any of several different ways that a single "mental" phoneme can be physically pronounced. You can swap around allophones in a word's sounds but until you instead change to a different phoneme. Until then, the listener will not "hear" a different word being said. That's why this does not matter.

Comment: @tchrist, have you heard my recorded audio files? they are quite different you know

Comment: There are different kinds of allophones, though. If they are in free variation, then it really does not matter at all which one a non-native speaker uses. If they are conditioned allophones, it's important to get the right one. Aspirated and unaspirated /t/ are often considered allophones, but a non-native speaker who uses unaspirated [t] in a word like "time" is at risk of being misunderstood as saying "dime," because this is not a position where unaspirated [t] normally occurs for native speakers. I think Tom is asking if there are any conditions that affect the level of aspiration here.

Comment: @sumelic, you are right. I am afraid that people misunderstood me if I say "unaspirated T before **tive**" for the word "**attractive**"

Comment: @sumelic, a lot of Indian do not aspirate T for words like "Time" or "Thai"

Comment: I haven't actually seen this written down anywhere, but this is my perceptions: Aspirated and unaspirated /t/ are in free variation at the beginnings of unstressed sylables after /k/, as well as in some other positions.  They are not in free variation after /s/ or at the beginnings of stressed syllables. Try listening to some other recordings of those words, and see if they have the same aspiration.